# What is the correct way writing video source URL with string and number

Tags: javascript, html

The code is very simple and I just dont’ know why I cannot show the video here. Now it is just a black box without any videoplay.I am sure there is something wrong with my variable type?

```
Var current = 1;
Var videosrc = '/show' + current;
res.write("<video src= videosrc /controls autoplay>");
```

Comment: You probably mean `"<video src='" + videosrc + "' /controls autoplay>"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
res.write("<video src='" + videosrc + "' autoplay>");
```

This concatnates the value in the variable `videosrc` to the rest of the string instead of just printing out `"videosrc"`